# XML Mixed content model with complex types SSIS error

Tags: xml, xslt, ssis, xsd, visual-studio-2015

I have an XML file for a government document and a XSD file that it references.  I'm trying to extract information from the XML (chemical name, UN, and hazard classification) and store it into a table in SQL Server 2014.  However, whenever I perform an ETL with an XML source, using SSIS, I get the error: `The XML Source Adapter does not support mixed content model on Complex Types`.  How can I work around this?  Some ideas I thought about and tried to understand better were:  using an XSLT transform on the XML to only retain the pertinent information or use C# and XPath to select only the nodes I want.  But this has turned into something a bit harder than I originally thought.  Any help or direction is appreciated.

http://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/bulkdata/CFR/2014/title-49/CFR-2014-title49-vol2.xml
http://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/bulkdata/CFR/resources/CFRMergedXML.xsd

Comment: You might want to flatten the xml to reduce hierarchy in the xml, perhaps this read will  help: http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2011/04/20/loading-complex-xml-using-ssis/

Comment: @J3FFK Great! Thanks, I'll read it!  Why can't I ever find stuff like that when I do google searches on my own haha.

Comment: I don't see any chemicals tables in the xml.  Which sections are you looking for?  Maybe Title 29 instead of 49?

Comment: @jdweng no that's the correct one if you'll go to this tag `<TTITLE>§ 172.101 Hazardous Materials Table</TTITLE>`  that is the beginning of the enumeration.  They are ordered alphabetically and list the name, UN number, and hazard and packing group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\CFR-2014-title49-vol2.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement chapter = doc.Descendants("GPOTABLE").Where(x => x.Element("TTITLE") != null && x.Element("TTITLE").Value == "§ 172.101 Hazardous Materials Table").FirstOrDefault();

            var results = chapter.Elements().Where(x => x.Name == "ROW" && x.Attribute("RUL") == null && (x.Elements("ENT").Count() == 14 || x.Elements("ENT").Count() == 2)).Select(y => new
            {
                chemical_name = y.Elements("ENT").Count() == 14 ? y.Elements("ENT").Skip(1).FirstOrDefault().Value
                   : y.Elements("ENT").Skip(1).FirstOrDefault().Value == ""  
                      ? string.Join("", y.Elements("ENT").Skip(1).FirstOrDefault().Descendants().Select(z => z.NextNode == null ? z.Value : z.Value + z.NextNode.ToString()).ToArray()) 
                      : string.Join("", y.Elements("ENT").Skip(1).FirstOrDefault().Value),
                classification = y.Elements("ENT").Count() == 14 ? y.Elements("ENT").Skip(2).FirstOrDefault().Value : null,
                UN = y.Elements("ENT").Count() == 14 ? y.Elements("ENT").Skip(3).FirstOrDefault().Value : null
            }).Where(a => a.chemical_name.Length > 0).ToList();
        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: whoa thanks!  That is an intense query.  How long does it take you to come up with something like that.  I have trouble formulating queries for what I want.  Any tips for developing this ability.  I've spent the last couple of hours dissecting your query and reading up on LINQ.

Comment: The xml is not very regular that is why I have so many conditions.  Acid, Sludge wasn't being displayed and there were a bunch of empty chemical names I eliminated.

Comment: really digging into your answer.  Do you think you can explain to me the purpose of this line `? string.Join("", y.Elements("ENT").Skip(1).FirstOrDefault().Descendants().Select(z => z.NextNode == null ? z.Value : z.Value + z.NextNode.ToString()).ToArray())`  At first I thought it had something to do with deleting the blank entries, but you took care of that with your last line.  Also `FirstOrDefault` in this line `"§ 172.101 Hazardous Materials Table").FirstOrDefault();` doesn't grab all the items because there are two `<LIST>` elements with that value, so I just removed and voila

Comment: Not really.  I hacked until I got it to work.  This code has to do with the cases where the chemical names said "see ..." referring to to another row in the table.   These listings had the text in multiple child elements (Descendants).  So I used string join to combine the multiple elements.  With Xml Linq the <tag>value</tag>  is obtained using NextNode.  But if a NextNode doesn't exist you will get an exception.  So you have to test for null.  Notice in the Join I using an empty string.  Normally you use Join to create CSV and the join character is a comma.

Comment: Ah I like it!  I've been using LINQ pad to test stuff really fun been at it for a while now.  Good practice!  Thanks

Comment: What I also noticed was that some chemical's hazard classification have more than one identifier.  Both identifiers are listed in Node 6 after the <ROW> element.  So instead of `y.Elements("ENT").Skip(2).FirstOrDefault().Value`  it should be `Skip(5)` I think.  However, because I want to input this into a database it would be nice to normalize the table and split each value into a separate column.  Someway to split the `classification` column based on the `,` delimiter.

Comment: I think ENT 6 is the chemical name of an organic chain.  You should pull out an organic chemistry text book and verify.  I suspect the it is not an identifier for molecule, but a chain on the organic compound where the name is only the chain (not entire molecule).